# Javascript. Проблема с массивом объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть кусок кода создающий массив объектов THREE.Mesh (Three.js)

```js
  this.multipleChoice = function(n){
    console.log('log'); //проверка
    editor.ray.setFromCamera(editor.mouse, editor.camera); 
    editor.intersects = editor.ray.intersectObjects(editor.cubes.children); //модель в зоне мышки?
    if(editor.intersects.length > 0){
      editor.MINTERSECTED[n] = editor.intersects[0].object; //объект присваивается опр. ячейке массива
    } else editor.mN--;
    console.log(editor.MINTERSECTED); //тест
  }
```

Но, вместо

Array[2]

0: THREE.Mesh   (многие параметры в объектах разные)

1: THREE.Mesh

length: 2

...

Происходит в консоли это:

Array[2]

1: THREE.Mesh

length: 2

...

(При вводе в консоль editor.MINTERSECTED[0] выводится undefined)

Можете помочь?

Comment: добавьте `console.log(n);` - нуля там, скорее всего, не появится.

Comment: Нуль там есть, вот в чем проблема, из массива потом нулевой элемент просто исчезает

Comment: добавьте `console.log(n);` внутри `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось довольно неожиданным: вместо объявления массива я должен был объявить объект типа THREE.Object3D, внутри которого есть массив children[]

```js
  this.multipleChoice = function(n){
    console.log('log'); //проверка
    editor.ray.setFromCamera(editor.mouse, editor.camera); 
    editor.intersects = editor.ray.intersectObjects(editor.cubes.children); //модель в зоне мышки?
    if(editor.intersects.length > 0){
      editor.MINTERSECTED.children[n] = editor.intersects[0].object; //editor.MINTERSECTED = new THREE.Object3D
    } else editor.mN--;
    console.log(editor.MINTERSECTED); //тест
  }
```